# Missing MediaManager debugging messages on receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, chromecast, google-cast, custom-receiver

After load is completed, i try to send the new status to the sender (an Android app). I try the following:

```
mediaManager.broadcastStatus(true, '', {media}, true);
mediaManager.sendStatus(senderId, requestId, true, {media}, true);
mediaManager.sendLoadComplete(media);
```

When I run my code, I have nothing related to this in the debugger. I was expecting a message from cast_receiver.js like: 'sending message' or an error but I just get nothing.

Even when I use: mediaManager.onMetadataLoadedOrig(media), i catch nothing, how can I know that I am sending something to the sender? Should I add a specific code?

I am expecting something like: [Unexpected connected message for already connected sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796197/unexpected-connected-message-for-already-connected-sender)

I am really new at this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: (1) are you sure those lines are being executed (based on the flow of your app)? (2) have you turned on logging?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Working fine now, I didn't set the debugging properly.